# can't open table setting window and get the error "Error getting DDL for object No database selected"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working on MySql workbench. I have some views but I can't open the table editing window and get this error "Error getting DDL for object No database selected" for some of the views.

[image]

I used to be able to open the editing window for all the views and edit.

But recently, all of sudden, the editing window for some views started not to open with that error.

I might think that there is lack of specifying its database name in the select query in some of the views. But, at the moment, I can't confirm what is inside. So, this is just my guess. But if this is true, how to fix it by adding database name in the views without open this editing window?

How could I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the problem is just workbench here. You need to select a database there. The view is alright. I can't tell you how exactly, however, I don't use workbench. Just the good ol' mysql cli

Comment: @fancyPants so, what I have to do is, either to re-install mysql workbench or use mysql CLI to fix sql in the views in question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the fact that MySQL Workbench requires a default database (schema) to be activated, in order to retrieve a number of things required for work. You can do that by simply double clicking the schema node you want in the schema tree, once you opened a connection. Its caption will then turn to bold to indicate that it is the current default schema.

Another option is to specify the default schema in the connection options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I faced it, I just restarted MySQL workbench and it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).